# XSLT combine multiple Parents

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT. I'm trying to create an XSLT

Here's the XML Code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="orders.xslt" type="text/xsl"?>
<report>
  <orders>
    <order>
      <order_id>123</order_id>
      <order_name>Doritos</order_name>
    </order>
    <order>
      <order_id>234</order_id>
      <order_name>Pringles</order_name>
    </order>
  </orders>
  <order_actions>
    <order_action>
      <order_id>123</order_id>
      <order_action_dt>27-06-2020 07.00</order_action_dt>
      <action_name>ordered</action_name>
    </order_action>
    <order_action>
      <order_id>123</order_id>
      <order_action_dt>27-06-2020 09.00</order_action_dt>
      <action_name>dispatched</action_name>
    </order_action>
    <order_action>
      <order_id>123</order_id>
      <order_action_dt>27-06-2020 15.00</order_action_dt>
      <action_name>delivered</action_name>
    </order_action>
    <order_action>
      <order_id>234</order_id>
      <order_action_dt>27-06-2020 07.30</order_action_dt>
      <action_name>ordered</action_name>
    </order_action>
    <order_action>
      <order_id>234</order_id>
      <order_action_dt>27-06-2020 09.50</order_action_dt>
      <action_name>dispatched</action_name>
    </order_action>
  </order_actions>
</report>

<!-- language: lang-xml -->


Here's my XSLT Code
```

[image]

What I would like to do is Group them Like below but not sure how.

[image]

---

UPDATE: Trying to add the XSLT Code but I'm getting an error
[image]

UPDATE 2: After Adding xsl:apply-template inside for-each

```
<xsl:for-each select="order">
          <table border="1">

            <tr>
              <td>
                ORDER_ID
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="order_id"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                ORDER_NAME
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="order_name"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/report/order_actions/order_action[order_id = ./order_id]" />

          </table>

        </xsl:for-each>
```

[image]

When I add the xsl-template after xsl:apply-templates

```
<xsl:for-each select="order">
      <table border="1">

        <tr>
          <td>
            ORDER_ID
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="order_id"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            ORDER_NAME
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="order_name"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/report/order_actions/order_action[order_id = ./order_id]" />
        <xsl:template match="order_action" >
          <tr>

          </tr>
        </xsl:template>
      </table>

    </xsl:for-each>
```

[image]

UPDATE 3: So I added the xsl:apply-templates like so

```
 <xsl:for-each select="order">
          <table border="1">

            <tr>
              <td>
                ORDER_ID
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="order_id"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                ORDER_NAME
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="order_name"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/report/order_actions/order_action[order_id = ./order_id]" />

          </table>

        </xsl:for-each>
```

Then added a new template outside the first template

```
<xsl:template match="order_action">

    <tr xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <td>Order Status</td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="action_name"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <td>Order Date</td>
      <td colspan="">
        <xsl:value-of select="order_action_dt"/>
      </td>
    </tr>    
  </xsl:template>
```

The problem now is it's showing all the order_action per order_id

[image]

Comment: Please post your input, XSLT and the expected output **as code**, not as pictures.

Comment: I tried putting the code as code but it's translating it. Is there another way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your code for the header row, you could achieve this by an

`<xsl:apply-templates select="/report/order_actions/order_action[order_id = current()/order_id]" />`

As well as a template to create the order action rows:

```
<xsl:template match="order_action" >
<tr>
....your code here
</tr>
</xsl:template>
```

The `select` on `apply-templates` filters the node-set of order_actions to those which match the order by id before invoking the template. The second template runs once per order_action in this node-set.

You may also want to sort them by the date they occurred, assuming they don't necessarily appear in the document in date order. In which case, add an

`<xsl:sort select="order_action_dt" order="descending" />`

inside the apply-templates.

**edit:**

I mistakenly used the shorthand for the *context* node `.` and not the *current* node `current()` - where the *context* node changes inside an XPath selector because it is evaluating a node-set and each one in turn becomes the context node. The current node is the node currently in scope for the template. Replacing `./order_id` for `current()/order_id` should get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Do I need to put this inside the for-each?

Comment: Assuming you'll have many orders and the following rows should be grouped by order_id (as I did), yes.

Comment: I've updated the example with 2 orders. and the screenshot.

Comment: Added UPDATE 3.

Comment: I think my understanding of the scoping of order_id in this context is flawed, bear with me, I'll correct this shortly.

Comment: Are there any good resource I could read about XSLT?

Comment: @ReydanGatchalian sadly none in particular other than the [XSLT spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116) (I am limited to XSLT 1.0 because I mainly program in .NET). I find it especially difficult to articulate XSLT-related programming problems as compared to other kinds of programming problems, so finding an answer from someone else's situation that applies to your situation is particularly difficult, and explaining to someone else what you want to achieve without examples is also difficult. The spec is really hard going but it's the only resource that actually says everything.

Comment: Thanks @TomW.  I also find it difficult to search for tutorial about this. Thank you so much. It's really a great help.